# Timestamp not correctly getting inserted into database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am inserting, through my below java code, a date value into a column of my table called `Source`.

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String todayDate = df.format(today).toString();
myVO.setMyDate(todayDate);
```

`myDao.saveOrUpdateVO(myVO);`

Later, I am retrieving the date value stored in `Source` table's column and inserting that date into `destination` table.

Now, I noticed that the date value stored in `Source` table is like below,

`18-Oct-2015 00:00:0`

Whereas the value stored in `destination` table is - `18-Oct-2015 08:15:0`.

Why is this difference? If I want to store date value in `Source` table just like how it is getting stored in `destination`, what I need to do?

Datatype of the column in both tables is `date default sysdate`

Comment: are you sure that the `destination` is displaying the date you inserted not the default sysdate? Try inserting 17th Oct in source and see that is destination. I suspect your date is not getting inserted in destination.

Comment: I am very much sure that date is getting inserted into `destination` from the value retrieved from `Source`. I have a partition created on `destination` table. If my `source` table has a `null` value in that column, insertion will not happen in `destination` table, because it will not be able to fit that `null` value into any partition

Comment: Do **not** use Strings to pass date or timestamp values. Use a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` together with a `PreparedStatement`. Show us the code that displays the value `18-Oct-2015 08:15:0`  it might well just be a formatting issue when _displaying_ the data, not a problem when saving it.

Comment: You populate your SOURCE table with `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")` which lacks a time element, so obviously the populated date has no time element.  You haven't shown us how you populate the DESTINATION table, so we cannot explain the discrepancy you claim exists.